# Why are the 21 combinations not equally likely?

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading "knowing the odds" and have a question about the symmetry principle.

> **Symmetry Principle.** If two events are indistinguishable except for the way the outcomes are labeled, they are equally likely.

Here is an example

> Roll a die and consider the events "even" and "odd", {2,4,6} and {1,3,5}. If we physically renumber the faces of the die, so we interchange n and 7-n, we turn 1 to 6, 2 to 5 and 3 to 4, then the events "even" and "odd" are interchanged. The symmetry principle says that the two events have the same probability

Now for the next example, a pair of dice. he states the following

> we can write the outcomes as 36 equally likely ordered pairs. So, for instance, the point 12 can only be made by (6,6), so it has probability 1/36, while the point 11 can be made with (5,6) or (6,5), so it has probability 2/36.
>
> But, in fact, a pair of dice are usually of the same color, and essentially indistinguishable. This led Gottfried Leibniz to write that points 11 and 12 were equally likely. This was because each point can be made in only one way: the 12 by two sixes, the 11 by a six and a five.
>
> This contradicts the previous calculation

here's the problem

> Why are the 21 combinations not equally likely? (Hint: Is it possible to relabel the dice to change any given combination into any other? If it is, the symmetry principle would tell us Leibnitz was right, and we would have a genuine problem!)

Can someone help me explain this? I also don't understand the so-called "relabeling"

Comment: Right, so if you have a red die and a blue die, then throwing $11$ is twice as likely as throwing $12$, but if you paint the blue die red, then throwing $12$ now becomes equally likely as throwing $11$?

Comment: A good example to keep in mind is lottery tickets. There are only two possibilities for lottery tickets: win or lose. Does that mean you have a 50% chance of winning?

Answer (score 1):

So long as there are two dice, or the same dice rolled twice, there are two ways of making $11$ whether the dice are distinguishable or not. One dice must show a $5$ (two possibilities) and the other a $6$ (one possibility) - total two possibilities.

In the terminology of your question, the two ways of getting $11$ are indistinguishable, hence equally likely.

Comment: Then why 21 combinations are not equally likely?

Comment: @Vector because the doubles are obtainable in only one way. Taking six doubles and fifteen other combinations we have $6+2\times 15 =36$ which accords with the total number of possible combinations.

Comment: @Vector If the dice were different colors, it's clear, isn't it, that 11 is twice as likely as 12? If you paint the dice to look the same, that doesn't change the probabilities since the sums come out the same on every roll. So there's no reason to believe that the 21 distinguishable outcomes are equally likely in the first place. If you flip 5 identical pennies, do you think 5 heads should be equally likely as (3 heads, 2 tails)?

Answer (score -1):

Leibnitz was correct but the question, as typically put, is malformed by including the word FAIR. The answer is based on an assumption that is not imposed by the question.

Two dice are only FAIR if all 36 outcomes have equal probability. This is how two FAIR dice are typically employed. However, further applying an UNFAIR rule of adding the results has the effect of LOADING the dice with only 11 outcomes (2-12) of unequal probabilities. Alternatively, one could apply a rule where the two numbers are **multiplied** - and that would be even less FAIR because of the 18 possible results, 5 results occur once (1/18), 10 occur twice (1/9), 1 thrice (1/6) and two four times (2/9).

It is a common trick to omit any indication in the question that FAIR does not apply to the outcome of the LOADING rule. Because of the intentional misuse of the word FAIR, one could quite rightly assert that each possible sum (2-12) has the SAME PROBABILITY of occurring. This is the exact scenario involving electronic simulations of 2 dice where FAIR or LOADED odds can be very easily programmed (reverse engineered) to have equal probability. The answer given is thus LOADED with a contradictory ASSUMPTION about the meaning of FAIR. Take out the word "FAIR" altogether and then the question itself would be FAIR.

A famous case of a malformed question involving world's smartest woman Marilyn vos Savant and the Monte Hall problem shows how an assumption made in Marilyn's purported answer was never imposed by the question. Look it up!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).